# In app purchase throws 0x80004005 error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using below code to try in app purchase in my wp8 app. Everything seems to be fine, however when the user clicks on the item to purchase and then quickly clicks the Back button the exception is thrown

> {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error
>   HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

The message is very clear, It's because using the `await` in below code

```
await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productId, false);
ProductLicense productLicense = null;
if (CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses.TryGetValue(productId, out productLicense))
{
   if (productLicense.IsActive)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Thank you for purchasing!!!");
      CurrentApp.ReportProductFulfillment(productId);
      return;
    }
}

MessageBox.Show("Your purchase was not succefull, please try again");
```

I am wondering how to remove the exception?

Thanks!

Comment: you cant remove it but you can handle it with a try catch.

Comment: Thanks, I already added try/catch, but was looking for proper handling :)

Comment: Error reporting in WP8 isn't always stellar.  A pretty inevitable consequence of very different runtimes trying to talk to each other.  But whatever you hope for, you'll never get an ERROR_YOU_CLICKED_THE_BACKBUTTON error code out of it.  Getting a generic "it didn't work" error code is not uncommon.  It didn't work, you already know why it didn't work, it isn't critical to keep your program running.  So just catch it and move on with your life.